# How to center a web page

Tags: html, css

I want to position my webpage so that on zooming in or out, the webpage diminishes or increases in size from the center. For example while zooming in or out this website, the layout moves towards the center and away from it. I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are talking about margin:0px auto; 
All you have to do is add this to the body in CSS :-

```
body{
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Go to this link for further details :- 
http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

I hope this helps...

Comment: The width:1000px; should also be added to the body tag style

Answer (score 1):

```
.yourContainerClass{ margin:0 auto; width:1000px;}
```